# Can I split my C# class across multiple files?

Tags: c#

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public static class ReferenceData
{

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAnswerType()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1 answer"  },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2 answers" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3 answers" }
            };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDatastore()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "DEV", Text = "Development"  },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "DC1", Text = "Production" }
            };
    }
    public static string GetDatastoreText(string datastoreValue)
    {
        return GetDatastore().Single(s => s.Value == datastoreValue).Text;
    }
    public static string GetDatastoreValue(string datastoreText)
    {
        return GetDatastore().Single(s => s.Text == datastoreText).Value;
    }

    // Lots more here
    // Lots more here

}
```

There's a lot more that I didn't show above.

Currently all of the class information is in one file. However I would like to split this into multiple files. Is there some way that I can spread the contents of the ReferenceData class across more than one file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, include the keyword `partial` in the class declaration in every file where you do so.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: Partial classes must be having the same namespace, just an info.

Answer (score 57):

Yes, you can use [partial classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx). This allows you to split your class over multiple files.

File 1:

```
public static partial class ReferenceData
{
    /* some methods */
}
```

File 2:

```
public static partial class ReferenceData
{
    /* some more methods */
}
```

Use this feature carefully. Overuse can make it hard to read the code.

Comment: +1. However, consider using regions to organise the code better within a single file. If you still 'need' several files it is usually a sign that your class is not well designed. Consider breaking it into several classes with clearly defined jobs/behaviours.

Comment: @JasonWilliams Agreed but keep in mind that there are cases where partial classes are necessary, such as in asp mvc where half the class is auto-generated, and you may want to add to it.

Answer (score 12):

Yes you can of course, just use the `partial` keyword before the `class` keyword at all declarations. For example,  make 4 different files (but in the same namespace) containing methods and members for the `ReferenceData` class  like this:

File1.css

```
public static partial class ReferenceData
{

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAnswerType()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "1 answer"  },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "2 answers" },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "3 answers" }
            };
    }
}
```

File2.cs

```
public static partial class ReferenceData
{

    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetDatastore()
    {
        return new[]
            {
                new SelectListItem { Value = "DEV", Text = "Development"  },
                new SelectListItem { Value = "DC1", Text = "Production" }
            };
    }
}
```

File3.cs

```
public static partial class ReferenceData
{

    public static string GetDatastoreText(string datastoreValue)
    {
        return GetDatastore().Single(s => s.Value == datastoreValue).Text;
    }
    public static string GetDatastoreValue(string datastoreText)
    {
        return GetDatastore().Single(s => s.Text == datastoreText).Value;
    }
}
```

File4.cs

```
public static partial class ReferenceData
{

    // Lots more here
    // Lots more here
}
```