# Can I Split my C# local method across multiple files?

Tags: c#, methods

I have this:

(note: this is not the main file, that's why it doesn't have the Main method)

```
namespace MJeC_Sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Game() 
        {
            Move();

            void Move()
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have void Move() on another file while keeping the conveniences of not having to pass variables to it?

Comment: Short answer: No, as far as variables declared in the Game() method are concerned. Long answer: If the code in the Move() method (a local method) depends on variables declared in the Game() method, then the Move() method will only have _direct_ access to those Game() method variables when it is a local non-static method declared inside Game(). If you move the Move() method to somewhere else (or make it static), well, you know where this is going now...

Comment: A main is only needed if you are starting the code from Windows.   Only one project needs a main.  When you have a class project that is called from another project is doesn't need a main.  It does hurt to have a main, but it is not required.

Comment: Why do you want a local method if you want to split it?

Answer (score 1):

No, local methods have to be written inside the text of their outer method and there is no way to split a single method into multiple files.

It is possible to split the same class into multiple files - so a non-local method can be easily written in a separate file - [Can I split my C# class across multiple files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7939034/can-i-split-my-c-sharp-class-across-multiple-files).

Note that in C/C++ you can do something like that by using pre-processor's `#include` statement - C# does not support that, but if you really need such functionality and your team is comfortable with modifying build you can try using C preprocessor to do includes before compiling code with C#. Note that the source code will no longer pass C# syntax checks (as included methods will be missing) - so it probably not useful for human readable code (maybe useful in some code gen cases ).